# Different interval time between two UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I have two **UIDatePicker** and i want to display from and two time
so if i select time as **4:30** then in another UIDatePicker it will show from 6:30 , So I want to 2 Hours Interval time

So can anyone has any solution for this?

Please help me.

```
  let datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
  datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
  txtFrom.inputView = datePickerView
  datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)




func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    txtFrom.text = timeFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    let datePickerTo  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerTo.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    let date1 = timeFormatter.date(from: txtFrom.text!)
    datePickerTo.minimumDate = date1?.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 2)
    txtTo.inputView = datePickerTo
    datePickerTo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChangedTO), for: .valueChanged)


}


func datePickerValueChangedTO(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        if Validate .isEmpty(txtFrom.text) {
            Util.invokeAlertMethod("ReHydration", strBody: "Please Select From Time", delegate: nil)
            return
        }
        else
        {
            let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            txtTo.text = timeFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
            let date1 = timeFormatter.date(from: txtFrom.text!)
            let date2 = timeFormatter.date(from:  txtTo.text!)

            let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
            let components: DateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.hour, .minute ], from: date1!, to: date2!)
            print(components)
            var returnString:String = ""
            print(components.minute!)
            if components.hour! <= 120 && components.minute! <= 60 {
                returnString = "Just Now"
            }else if components.minute! >= 1{
                returnString = String(describing: components.minute) + " min ago"
            }else if components.hour! >= 1{
                returnString = String(describing: components.hour) + " hour ago"
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement this functionality using `addingTimeInterval` method.

define variable to store date of first datepicker.

```
var fromTime: Date?
```

When you finish to select date from `datePickerView` save the `datePickerView.date` into fromTime variable.

After that, for `datePickerTo` set `minimumDate` property for that DatePicker like below.

```
datePickerTo.minimumDate = fromTime?.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 2) // 2 hour interval
```

So, it will open date picker which is 2 hours forward time than `datePickerView`.

Hope you will get your idea.

Comment: @VimalBosamiya Can you update code after trying above solution.?

Comment: it should be datePickerTo.setDate (fromTime?.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 2), animated: false)

Comment: should set date property not minimumDate property.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker